# I am not sure how to check the action attribute?

Tags: php, forms

Some thing is wrong in this code, because when i press the submit button the code inside this block of code it is not executed. 
Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST["form"])) {
    if (Form::isValid($_POST["form"])){
        include 'config_php/insert_lead.php';   

    } else{
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
    exit(); 
}
}
```

This is a small portion of the form:

```
<form action="index.php?s=2468" id="multiphase" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" class="form-control shadow" name="first_name" required="" placeholder="Voornaam:" id="multiphase-element-22">
<input type="text" class="form-control shadow" name="last_name" required="" placeholder="Achternaam: " id="multiphase-element-23">
<input type="email" class="form-control shadow" name="email1" required="" placeholder="E-mailadres:" id="multiphase-element-28">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="multiphase-element-29">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

One more thing the form is generated using [PFBC](http://www.imavex.com/pfbc3.x-php5/index.php#getting-started)

Comment: Can you also post your HTML?

Comment: Check whether the name of the submit button match the if(isset($_POST["form"]))

Comment: Check if your submit button is within the <form> </form> tags

Comment: `if(isset($_POST["submit"])) `

Comment: Unless you have a variable in your form called "form", your code won't work. I don't know what your `Form::isValid()` method is supposed to be doing, but I have a feeling that it should access the whole $_POST. Or perhaps all inputs in your form must be named like `form[input_name]` to create the POST variable your script is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a post value named 'form', so you should set one to look for on the submission.

Notice that I have also used the entire POST array in the Form::isValid() check.

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["postback"])) {
    $valid = true;
    if (Form::isValid($_POST)){
        include 'config_php/insert_lead.php';   
    } else{
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
        exit(); 
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="index.php?s=2468" id="multiphase" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="form-control shadow" name="first_name" required="" placeholder="Voornaam:" id="multiphase-element-22">
        <input type="text" class="form-control shadow" name="last_name" required="" placeholder="Achternaam: " id="multiphase-element-23">
        <input type="email" class="form-control shadow" name="email1" required="" placeholder="E-mailadres:" id="multiphase-element-28">
        <input type="hidden" name="postback" value="1">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="multiphase-element-29">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `$_POST["form"]` is the fault you doing...

if you are using `$_POST["form"]` then it means you have named any of your input field as "**form**" which i dont see in your code...

so instead of `$_POST["form"]` you should use any of the input name you using...
I suggest to use..
`$_POST["submit"]` instead of `$_POST["form"]` 
because you have already named submit input field as submit...
See if it help

Answer (score 0):

Change `form` tor `submit`:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (Form::isValid($_POST["form"])){
        include 'config_php/insert_lead.php';   

    } else{
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
    exit(); 
}
}
```

The the `if` will be executed BUT the you will still have problems with the next `if` (`Form::isValid($_POST["form"])`) I don't know how `isValid` works but `$_POST["form"]` does not exist. You can validate all inputs one by one.